# How to store and return the array with the squared result from array in method parameters

Tags: java

```
public class Practise
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] array = {1.0,2.0,2.0,4.0};
        System.out.println(square(array));
    }
    public static double[] square (double[] a)
    {
        double [] squared = new double[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i <a.length ; i++)  {
            squared[i] = a[i] * a[i];
        }
        return squared;
    }
```

I'm trying to update squared array with the result of a array's values squared and then return it 
but I'm keep getting an [D@1540e19d error , sorry if it is a easy question I am a student just started learning java!`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the array object reference, you should print each cell of your array, try:

```
public class Practise
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] array = {1.0,2.0,2.0,4.0};
        double[] result = square(array);

        for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
        {
          System.out.println("Square of " + array[i] + " is: " + result[i]);
        }

    }


    public static double[] square (double[] a)
    {
        double [] squared = new double[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i <a.length ; i++)  {
            squared[i] = a[i] * a[i];
        }
        return squared;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that really helped - makes a lot sense doing it this way !

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some modifications in your code:
For case 1:

```
public class Practise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = {1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 4.0};
        array = square(array); //to get new array from method
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
            System.out.println(array[i]); // print array by index
    }

    public static double[] square(double[] a) {
        double[] squared = new double[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            squared[i] = a[i] * a[i];
        }
        return squared;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1.0
4.0
4.0
16.0
```

For case 2:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Practise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = {1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 4.0};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(square(array)));
    }

    public static double[] square(double[] a) {
        double[] squared = new double[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            squared[i] = a[i] * a[i];
        }
        return squared;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[1.0, 4.0, 4.0, 16.0]
```

In the case 1 you can control and handle the output of the new array

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  System.out.println(square(array));
```

use :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(square(array)));
```

and see 
[What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array?noredirect=1&lq=1)

NB : D@1540e19d is not a error.It's the hashCode() in hexadecimal.
 See  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your program. You are printing the memory address of array, which is `[D@1db` something like this. it is vary(because it is memory address).

Change:

```
System.out.println(square(array));
```

To:

```
 System.out.println(square(array)[0]);
```

tihs will only print index `0` value. If you want to print all the values in array you can do like this:

```
for(Double d: square(array)){
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Here I have used for-each(enhanced for loop). If you are not familiar with this go with for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would create another array that stores the squared values of`double[] array = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};` . I don't think you need `double[] squared`inside the method. Just use the one that you have given in the parameterlist.

```
public class square {
public static void main (String[] args){
    double[] array = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
    double[] array1 = squareArray(array);
    for(double elem: array1){
        System.out.println(elem);
    }
}
public static double[] squareArray(double[] a){
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        a[i] *= a[i];
    }
    return a;
}
}
```

Array1 stores the squared values of array. I'm not quite sure what you're question is, but if it's about just printing out the array, the for-each-loop is a must-know for a beginner programmer. I've written it in the code. I'd **strongly** advice you to start using it and undertand its functionality. Hope this was helpful.